# Exception in strange class (generated code)

Tags: java, android

I am new to a project and are looking in crashlytics for crashes, one of the top crashes have the following stack trace:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Map se.domain.android.api.a.b.theMethod()' on a null object reference
           at se.domain.android.screen.zerohit.ZeroHitReportFragment.se.domain.android.api.request.MyRequest.zeroHitsRequest(SourceFile:4841)
```

First of all there are no class with that long package name and line number 4841, and the method is only called private, that seem strange way to get NPE?

So I am thinking this is some generated code? Any one have a clue?

Comment: debug and solve

Comment: Posting full stack trace might help.

Comment: Please can you share the  issue causing code snippet ???